# picker popup long text wrap xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using xamarin forms for my project.
I am using Picker in forms. When the picker items has long text, then it will wrap like multilines.
But it shows like below image:
[image]

I am using Renderer Page in android and add the below code:

```
Control.SetSingleLine(false);
```

But it is not working. Can anyone please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: not possible with picker, as an alternative solution, you can use the popup plugin, https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup

Comment: I believe wrap works when you have space in between? Have you tried it that way?

Comment: First, show us the code of your custom renderer. Make sure that you provide every relevant code that way it will be easier for us to help you :)

Comment: any update on this issue?